# date type: cannot convert unique date(object) to date type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unique, date-formatting

date type of original Dataflame is object type.  "23/07/01" means Year 2023, month 7, date 1

"23/07/01" is on 'data' column so I write code as below.

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format='%Y/%m/%d')

However the error below pops up
ValueError: time data "23/07/03" at position 0 doesn't match format specified

Answer (score 1):

`%Y` means year with century. You need to use `%y`. See the documentation on [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more information.

Using the format `"%y/%m/%d"` should give the output you expect.

```py
d = pd.to_datetime("23/07/01", format="%y/%m/%d")
print(d) # Timestamp('2023-07-01 00:00:00'
```